# Return values as array from collection

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

We have a collection of scrips :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxxx"),
    "scrip" : "3647"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("yyyyyy"),
    "scrip" : "5647"
}
...
```

We are simply attempting to return the scrip numerals as an array of string using java driver 3.7

```
ArrayList<Document> scriplist = scrips.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
                Aggregates.group(
                         Accumulators.push("scripids",
                                    new Document("_id", "$id").
                                            append("scripids", "$scripid"))
                )
                )).into(new ArrayList<>());

        System.out.println(scriplist.toString());
```

Expected output is `['3647','5647']`.

However,we get a `'Can't find a codec for class com.mongodb.client.model.BsonField.'` exception.
How is this to be done?

Comment: Please post valid input(two object IDs cannot be same) and the expected output.

Comment: Apologies for the oversight - edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.scrips.distinct("scrip");
```

Output:

```
["3647","5647"]
```

**Equivalent code in Java:**

```
DistinctIterable<String> iterable = scrips.distinct("scrip", String.class);
List<String> scrips = new ArrayList<>();
Block<String> block = scrip -> scrips.add(scrip);
iterable.forEach(block);
```

The 'scrips' set would hold the distinct scrips.

**Some other ways to do the same:**

```
db.scrips.aggregate([
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":"$scrip"
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":null,
            "scrips":{
                $push:"$_id"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0
        }
    }
])
```

**Java code:**

```
scrips.aggregate(
                Arrays.asList(Aggregates.group("$scrip"), Aggregates.group(null, Accumulators.push("scrips", "$_id")),
                    Aggregates.project(Projections.exclude("_id"))));
```

```
db.scrips.aggregate([
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":null,
            "scrips":{
                $addToSet:"$scrip"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0
        }
    }
])
```

**Java code:**

```
scrips.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.group(null, Accumulators.addToSet("scrips", "$_id")),
                Aggregates.project(Projections.exclude("_id"))));
```

Comment: Thanks.Wonderful solutions.Was trying to use push - is it possible though?

Comment: Yes, it is :). Do you want a solution with $push?

Comment: Yes  ..its a bug i need to uncover in existing code...and need ot understand how push works for it

Comment: Makes sense. Let me add that solution too.

Comment: Push doesnt seem to work unless I am mistaken - I actually get { "scrips" : [{ "$oid" : "xxxxx" }, { "$oid" : "xxxx" }, { "$oid" : "xxx" }] }

Comment: Got it.Needed to replace $id with $scrip!!